# How to get ID from select box using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I have the following `<select>` options, and I have to send id of the community i.e., `x.community_type_id` to fetch subcommunity.

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-click="sendID({{ x.community_type_id }})">{{ x.community_Type }}</option>
</select>
```

Right now I am using the following code to fetch data from web service to select option.

```
var app = angular.module('EntityApp', []);
    app.controller('EntityAppCntroller', function($scope, $http) {  
    $http.get("http://111.222.22.333:1081/apartment/community/type/list")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.type;
    }); 

    $scope.sendID = function (id) {
        alert(langKey);
    }
});
```

I want to send  x.community_type_id to a web service.
That webservice url is like this :

```
http://11.338.41.149:8481/apartment/register/sub/community/type
```

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, when an attribute starts with `ng-`, it is evaluated as JavaScript, hence you can do away with the double curly braces:

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-click="sendID(x.community_type_id)">{{ x.community_Type }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the curly brackets in the `ng-click` function

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-click="sendID( x.community_type_id )">{{ x.community_Type }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
html

```
 ng-click="sendID( x.community_type_id )"
```

js

```
  $scope.sendID = function (id) {
         $http({
          method:'GET',
          url:'yoururl'+id,
          data:{'id':id}
             ///
})        
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <select ng-model="model" ng-options="x.community_type_id as    
     x.community_Type for x in myData" ng-click="sendID(model)">
 <option ></option>
 </select>
```